# C++ How to overload the [] operator and make a function call

Tags: c++

Sorry. i do not know how to ask this question, so i will give a example.

1. Get the arg string from the command line
   Example: MyProgram.exe -logs=yes -console=no

   ```
   CmdLine CmdLine( ::GetCommandLine() );  // Get arg string.
   ```
2. When i have the arg string. i wish to look for "logs" ("yes") and "console" get its value
   ("no").

   ```
   CmdLine.GetKey["logs"].GetValue();      // Get the value of "logs".
   CmdLine.GetKey["console"].AsBool();     // Get the value of "console".
   ```

I have to overload the [] operator ( `void operator[] ( const std::string & str );` )

```
 GetKey["logs"]; // okay.
```

But i do not know how or if i can in C++ to do something like;

```
CmdLine.GetKey["console"].MyFunction();  // HOW to do this?
```

How can i tell "GetKey" to call "MyFunction(). (sorry for bad wording. but i do not know know
what this is called.

Thank you for patients and help and ideas.

EDIT:

Sorry for confusion!

```
 CmdLine.GetKey["logs"].GetValue(); // Example!!!
```

1. I overload the [] so i can look up "logs" in a std::map, std::unordered_map (whatever).
2. When i find "logs" i wish for "GetKey["logs"]" to call "GetValue()" and return
   the value.
   I do know know what this is called when i do this;

   Func().SomeFunc().SomeOtherFunc();

Because i want to do the example i tried to explain.

Comment: The `void` in `void operator[] ( const std::string & str );` means the function does not return anything, so you can't call `.MyFunction()` on the nothing returned.

Comment: Looks like you should be using `std::map<std::string, data>` or `std::unordered_map<std::string, data>` as the backing to `CmdLine` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Aside: I find it strange you have a data member named `GetKey`

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: what is `MyFunction` ?  A method of something?

Comment: @Caleth Why? Though in this case, `GetArg` or `GetArgByKey` might be clearer

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings -- the `Get` prefix is the problem. Data members don't usually perform actions. Their member functions do.

Comment: @PeteBecker Heh, true, didn't notice the `[`/`]`. Even though that's what the entire question is about. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

Lets dissect it step by step:

```
CmdLine.GetKey["logs"].GetValue();
                     // call method on some object
              // call operator [] on GetKey
// GetKey is a member of CmdLine
```

As mentioned in a comment, `GetKey` is not a good name for a member. I suppose you don't really need it, but it was just your attempt to express that you are looking up the object on which you want to call `GetValue()` in `CmdLine`. I have to admit, I don't fully understand the example. Anyhow...

You can make `operator[]` return an object that has a member function that you can call:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    std::string value;    
    void print() { std::cout << value; }
};

struct bar {
    foo operator[](const std::string& x) {
        return {x};
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bar b;
    b["hello world"].print();
}
```

Output:

```
hello world
```

For more on operator overloading read [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will read the link you post again. I also look at "function chaining" to see if this will help me. :)